# Modular pattern with DOM elements

Tags: javascript

I am trying to structure my Javascript using the module pattern.

```
var appTest = { 

    settings: { 
        date    : $(".date")
    }, 

    init: function() {
        s = this.settings; 
        this.setDate();
    },

    setDate: function() {
        var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
        var dt = new Date();
        s.date.html(dt.getDate()+" "+monthNames[dt.getMonth()]+" "+dt.getFullYear());
        //$(".date").html(dt.getDate()+" "+monthNames[dt.getMonth()]+" "+dt.getFullYear());
    }

}; 

$(function(){
    appTest.init(); 
});
```

Right now, the dom element with class .date doesn't get updated with the new date. However if I uncomment the line that is commented, it works just fine.

I am still trying to find my way around Javascript.

Comment: Are you sure DOM is loaded before appTest is defined?

Comment: Dod you know, `this` will vary in `s = this.settings`? You need to call it as `appTest.init.call(appTest)` to make `this` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some problems in your module :

- it uses a global variable, `s`, without declaring it and with risks of name collision. You should embed it
- you expose the settings
- you use the DOM before it's ready
- you call `setDate` on an object which doesn't have this function

You could fix those problems like this :

```
var appTest = (function(){ 
    var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
    var settings = {}; // this is private (not visible from outside the module)
    var module = {};
    module.init = function() {
        settings.date = $(".date");
        module.setDate();
    };
    module.setDate = function() {
        var dt = new Date();
        settings.date.html(dt.getDate()+" "+monthNames[dt.getMonth()]+" "+dt.getFullYear());
    };
    return module;
})(); 

$(function(){
    appTest.init(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the use of prototypes. You can make a singleton like:

```
var App = (function AppModule() {

  function App() {
    // All your options here
    this.$date = $('.date');
    this.init(); // initialize singleton
  }

  App.prototype = {

    init: function() {
      this.setDate();
    },

    setDate: function() {

      var months = [...]
        , monthsdate = new Date;

      this.$date.html(...);
    }
  };

  return new App; // a singleton

}());
```

Comment: Why use prototypes for a singleton ?

Comment: Why not use prototypes? It's just a different approach, nothing negative about it that I know of...